# Needs keyword in gitlab ci is not running

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am new to gitlab ci. Trying to run job based on `needs` keyword in gilab ci. Job `test-dev-case3` and `install-dev` has a `needs` keyword which should run as soon as when `Compile-dev` job is successfully run. But  both `test-dev-case3` and `install-dev` are running sequentially not running once `Compile-dev` job completes. Can someone explain why this is happening?

##### sample ci to understand flow

```yaml
stages:
  - compile
  - unit_test
  - integration_test
  - install
  

Compile-dev:
  stage: compile
  tags:
      - v01
  script:
    - echo "Maven compileing"
    - mvn compile
    
UnitTest-dev:
  stage: unit_test
  tags:
      - v01  
  script:
    - echo "Running unit test"
    - mvn clean test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
    reports:
       junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
    

test-dev-case1:
  stage: integration_test
  tags:
      - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
      
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
    - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target\cucumber-html-reports\
      
test-dev-case2:
  stage: integration_test
  tags:
      - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
  only:
    refs:
      - CICD_1  
      
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
    - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target\cucumber-html-reports\

test-dev-case3:
  stage: integration_test
  tags:
      - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
  only:
    refs:
      - master  
      
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
    - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
    
  needs: ["Compile-dev"]
  
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target\cucumber-html-reports\

test-dev-case4:
  stage: integration_test
  tags:
      - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
    
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
  
      
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
    - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target\cucumber-html-reports\      
  

install-dev:
  stage: install
  tags:
      - v01
  script:
    - mvn install -DskipCukes=true
  needs: ["Compile-dev"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before jumping to solution, please post code in `code` format.

Needs in gitlab are meant to link stages. Relationships between jobs that use needs can be visualized as a directed acyclic graph in a tab near your CI build. The syntax is pretty simple.

As per the documentation here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

```
linux:build:
  stage: build

mac:build:
  stage: build

lint:
  stage: test
  needs: []

linux:rspec:
  stage: test
  needs: ["linux:build"]

linux:rubocop:
  stage: test
  needs: ["linux:build"]

mac:rspec:
  stage: test
  needs: ["mac:build"]

mac:rubocop:
  stage: test
  needs: ["mac:build"]

production:
  stage: deploy
```

The below should be your gitlab ci config

```
stages:
  - compile
  - unit_test
  - integration_test
  - install

compile-dev:
  stage: compile
  tags:
    - v01
  script:
    - echo "Maven compileing" - mvn compile

unittest-dev:
  stage: unit_test
  tags:
    - v01
  script:
    - echo "Running unit test" - mvn clean test
  artifacts:
    when:
      always 
    expire_in:
        1 week 
    reports:
        junit: target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

test-dev-case1:
  stage: integration_test
  tags:
    - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something" - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
  artifacts:
    when:
      always 
    paths:
        - target\cucumber-html-reports\

test-dev-case2:
  stage: integration_test
  tags:
    - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
  only:
    refs:
      - CICD_1
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something" - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
  artifacts:
    when:
      always 
    paths:
        - target\cucumber-html-reports\

test-dev-case3:
  stage: integration_test
  needs: ["compile-dev"]
  tags:
    - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something" - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline
  artifacts:
    when:
      always 
    paths:
        - target\cucumber-html-reports\

test-dev-case4:
  stage: integration_test 
  tags:
    - v01
  before_script:
    - echo "Job one for test"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something" - mvn verify -P qa-pipeline 
  artifacts:
    paths:
        - target\cucumber-html-reports\
    when:
      always 
    

install-dev:
  stage: install
  needs: [ "compile-dev" ]
  tags:
      - v01 
  script:
      - mvn install -DskipCukes=true
```

Gitlab provides a nice feature (https://gitlab.com/org-name/project-name/-/ci/lint) to lint your CI config and also visualize a sample pipeline

Comment: Thank you for the response @Aswath , I used the same YML file u mentioned in the comment but still, the test-dev-case3 and install-dev are not getting execute once Compile-dev job get completes. My jobs are running in a sequence order, will it be because of this my two jobs with needs keyword is not running instantly. Please  let me your thought on this.

Comment: I think you might take a look to "dependencies".

> needs Execute jobs earlier than the stage ordering.

But, by default each stage is using all artifacts generated at previous stage. You can use the dependencies to setup which artifacts are needed to next job.

> dependencies Restrict which artifacts are passed to a specific job by providing a list of jobs to fetch artifacts from.
You can try to add 

test-dev-case3:
  dependencies : 
    - compile-dev
install-dev:
  dependencies : 
    - compile-dev

source : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/